# PHP session clearing out on page refresh - show and hide based on input

Tags: php, session, cookies

So I have two pages, both pages have an input field, and if the user fills out the input field and goes to the next page they will see new content in the form's place. So it's basically like "fill out this form and show new content". Whether you fill out the form on page A or page B, the other page will recognize if you have filled it out or not. Make sense?

I have it working as long as you don't refresh the page or get to the other page other than clicking the submit input.

What am I doing wrong here?

```html
<!--- Page A -->

<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" name="viewport">
 <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots">
 <title>Page A</title>
 <meta content="Page" name="description">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

   
 <form action="/b.php" id="l-form" method="post" name="l-form">
  <div class="wrapper localize" style="<?php if(isset($_POST['treasure'])) { echo "display:none;"; } else { echo "display:block;"; } ?>">
      <div class="header_container">
        <h2>Make sure we offer service at your location</h2>
      </div>        
      <div class="input_container">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="input-box street" id="street" name="userLogin" placeholder="Street address" tabindex="0" type="text">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="input-box suite" id="suite" name="suite" placeholder="Suite (Optional)" tabindex="0" type="text">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="input-box zipcode" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip code" tabindex="0" type="text">
            <input type="submit" name="treasure" value="See offers">
        </div>
    </div>
      <!-- results 3 -->
      <div class="results" style="<?php if(isset($_POST['treasure'])) { echo "display:block;"; } else { echo "display:none;"; } ?>">
        <p class="results-heading">Excellent news. We know who you are.</p
      </div>
 </form>
  
 

</body>
</html>

<!--- Page B -->

<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" name="viewport">
 <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots">
 <title>Page A</title>
 <meta content="Page" name="description">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

   
 <form action="/a.php" id="l-form" method="post" name="l-form">
  <div class="wrapper localize" style="<?php if(isset($_POST['treasure'])) { echo "display:none;"; } else { echo "display:block;"; } ?>">
      <div class="header_container">
        <h2>Make sure we offer service at your location</h2>
      </div>        
      <div class="input_container">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="input-box street" id="street" name="userLogin" placeholder="Street address" tabindex="0" type="text">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="input-box suite" id="suite" name="suite" placeholder="Suite (Optional)" tabindex="0" type="text">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="input-box zipcode" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip code" tabindex="0" type="text">
            <input type="submit" name="treasure" value="See offers">
        </div>
    </div>
      <!-- results 3 -->
      <div class="results" style="<?php if(isset($_POST['treasure'])) { echo "display:block;"; } else { echo "display:none;"; } ?>">
        <p class="results-heading">Excellent news. We know who you are.</p
      </div>
 </form>
  
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your not using any session variables; refresh reloads the page http is stateless , its working as i would expect currently

Comment: I added $_SESSION['treasure'] = $_POST['treasure']; to the top of the page and it still isn't working. What am I missing? After the user hits submit, I want the input fields to hide and new div to show with other content. Maybe this isnt possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using session variables anywhere.  When someone submits your form, you need to do something like:

```
$_SESSION['treasure'] = $_POST['treasure'];
```

to set the 'treasure' session variable.  On the other page or after a refresh, you can then access $_SESSION['treasure'].

Currently, this seems to work when you click submt, because you are making $_POST['treasure'] available to the target page, not because you are using sessions as intended.

Comment: I'm really new to this and trying to wrap my head around it. I just added $_SESSION['treasure'] = $_POST['treasure']; to the top of the page and it still isnt working. What am I missing? After the user hits submit, I want the input fields to hide and new div to show with other content.

Comment: @Phillyday It's ok.  After you set $_SESSION['treasure'], you want to check for it instead of $_POST['treasure'] later on.  So, instead of checking for $_POST['treasure'] to determine if the input fields show or not, check $_SESSION['treasure'].  The basic misunderstanding here is that HTTP is stateless, and $_POST only exists on the page where you post your data, $_SESSION sticks around until it expires or something triggers session_destroy() or after 1440 seconds.

Comment: How would I check for $_SESSION[‘treasure’] ? Would it be here: style="<?php if(isset($_POST['treasure'])) { echo "display:none;"; } else { echo "display:block;"; } ?>".    Or do I add something somewhere else?

Comment: If you set $_SESSION['treasure'] = $_POST['treasure'] early on, then replace every other use of $_POST['treasure'] with $_SESSION['treasure'].  You can learn more about sessions in PHP here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp, and more about HTTP Requests in PHP here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Comment: Thank you so much! what you suggested worked like charm. Thank you for being patient with me and for sending those links over.